# Can anyone tell me the meaning of this sentence "They lick around the edges of the firewood."?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrase-usage

Does "lick" here mean like "pass the tongue over"? 
I just start learning English, so i don't get this well. 
Here is the original: 
"The flames and embers look so pretty as they lick around the edges of the firewood , the tips of the bonfire reaching up to the sky." 
Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is very common to describe fire as _tongues_. The movement of the flames is like the movement of a tongue, and described as _licking_.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lick defn 3 under the "verb" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several verbs can be used figuratively (often metaphorically) to provide more clarity, and convey a more realistic description.

- "The waves **licked** the sides of the boat" (comparing waves to tongues)
- "I feel **bitten** by remorse"
- "I spent the afternoon **chewing** on the difficulties I was about to face".
- "He seemed to be **fishing** for compliments."

  "The flames and embers look so pretty as they lick around....**as they lightly touch and go over**... the edges of the firewood , the tips of the bonfire reaching up to the sky."

Answer (score 0):

Flames can be referred to in English as tongues - even the [Bible](http://biblehub.com/acts/2-3.htm) has references: "And there appeared unto them cloven tongues like as of fire, and it sat upon each of them."

Since the flame can be a tongue, it's motion can be a licking motion as would be for a literal tongue.  This can really be used for any reference to fire, but seems to be (looking for some validation on this) regarding smaller, controlled fires, as a cooking fire, campfire, et cetera.  Flames can "lick" the meat on the grill in much the same way.  I believe this is because licking is a relatively delicate action.  I've personally never heard of a forest fire licking the neighborhood, or anything of that nature.  I'm trying to conjure a word for that but can't seem to at the moment.